# Flash bot detection

Tags: flash, bots

Let's say I am making a very simple online Flash game:

- How can I detect bots playing my game. Do I have to analyze user clicks, mouse movements, etc ? Or is there simpler ways to detect bots.
- What would be the preferred way to code such a bot (so I can test my anti-bot). From some research, it looks like this could be done in Java (using the Robot class). Is there any better alternatives?

Basically looking for any and all information on that matter. I've looked at topics discussing this subject but I can't say they've enlightened me much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how in depth you want to get, but this article has some information:
https://iseclab.org/papers/botdetection-article.pdf

Basically you keep track of data from every user and look at a few specific data points to see if any players differ heavily from the average user.

You could use anything to code the bot... autohotkey, python, java, etc. For a flash game you just need to move the mouse around and maybe collect pixel data.